# Mold growth in attic, best DIY solution (if that's even possible)?

Tags: attic, mold

Discovered a leak in a bedroom ceiling after a particularly severe rainstorm. When I went into the attic, I discovered the mold as shown in the pictures. I went on the roof and it seems that some shingles blew off and is most likely the source of the leak. I can replace the shingles, but what is the step-by-step process to safely remove these mold growths? I was planning on wearing an N 95 mask, going up with a scraper, and knocking these growths into a box, which I would then dispose of outside. Then, I was thinking of maybe spraying the area with a bleach water mixture? Then, I figured I would post here first to get some more informed input before I did anything!

[image]

Comment: Or this? [What is the recommended way to destroy mold?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/14680/what-is-the-recommended-way-to-destroy-mold)

Comment: I've wondered for a while now if you could treat established mold with copper azole. It would certainly discourage mold from returning.

Comment: Never scrape the wood the spores go deep and you will damage the OSB, spray with hydrogen peroxide for best results , bleach works if you can handle the smell and don’t mind the bleach residue, hydrogen peroxide breaks down to water and oxygen.

Comment: boric acid will kill fungus of any sort.

Comment: @EdBeal  How are you doing?  Miss you on this site.